# Upgrade SharePoint 2010 to 2013 database attach method - Prevent errors

Tags: 2010, 2013, upgrade

I have to get information on How-to upgrade from SP 2010 to 2013. I read that the only way is database-attach.

As I never did this, and I'll probable do it for a customer, I wanted to ask this question, to know what kind of information is precious in order to prepare this upgrade.

I first want to ask OS/SQL Version, installation type (farm, standalone), Users number, any deployed solutions, ssl certificates, account type used.

If I understood the migration process, I have to install a new SP2013 server (depending the type), then I move content databases from 2010 to 2013 server, finally I create web application with these databases ?
So I can connect to the site and click settings -> try upgrade.

Is that everything I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262483(v=office.15).aspx) is the microsoft documentation for the upgrade process from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013. The documentation contains steps to create a SP2013 farm also. Apart from Content databases, you can also upgrade your service applications from SP2010 to SP2013 by upgrading the databases. [This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303436(v=office.15).aspx) will provide you good information.It contains the check-list to ensure you have everything in place before you start the database attach and upgrade.

Another important thing you need to make sure is the customizations used in SharePoint 2010 if any need to be upgraded to SharePoint 2013. [Here](http://zimmergren.net/technical/upgrading-your-sharepoint-2010-visual-studio-projects-and-solutions-to-sharepoint-2013) is a good resource to follow to upgrade the Visual studio 2010 solutions to VS2012.

Apart from database attach method, you can migrate the CONTENT databases using third party tools (try searching the net and you will find a bunch of them). But it certainly has some more cost associated with it and depends on you/customer to decide.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I already had these links bookmarked ;) But this is nice to know that ppl use them too. So I'll keep calm and use technet's ressources. Thanks.

Comment: Yes :) the documentation is quite good, though you have to refer to a couple of other posts/resources while you are testing the actual upgrade implementation. Off course, following the complete set of steps in a test environment will be the best approach to get detailed insight into the process and issues that might occur.